# How to find exact set of values within a column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

Example:

Table is:

[image]

So i want to return '123' and '456' with or without any NON NUMERIC VALUE either side.
So:

- 123
- (123,
- ,123,
- ,123)

Are all fine.

But

01234

is not what i want returned.

So my query should return rows '1' and '2' but not 3.

Comment: `(123|456)` is `123` or `456`. You could do `where data like '%123%' and date like '%456%'`. or you want the explicit numbers `123` and `456`?

Comment: I want explicitly '123'. NOT 1234.

Comment: Maybe `(^|[^0-9])123([^0-9]|$)` and then do another one for `456`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE data LIKE '% 123 %'
AND data LIKE '% 456 %'
```

I'd rather go this way and try to use `LIKE` wildcard instead of `regexp`.

This query would `SELECT` "all" `FROM` table `WHERE` `DATA` have a string "123" and `DATA` have a string "456".

**EDIT:**

Added spaces between % and numbers so that it won't search for string inside longer strings (for example it won't find 456 inside '123456789' anymore, but will find it inside '123 456 789').

**EDIT2:**

Actually the example given above would work ONLY if you have the string surrounded by spaces. In fact `regexp` might be more suitable in your case. I'd suggest, as mentioned below, to use word boundaries like so:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATA REGEXP '[[:<:]]123[[:>:]]';
AND DATA REGEXP '[[:<:]]456[[:>:]]';
```

**EDIT3:**

The perfect way in your case would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATA REGEXP '(^|[^0-9])123([^0-9]|$)';
AND DATA REGEXP '(^|[^0-9])456([^0-9]|$)';
```

Tested at http://regexp.pl/, you can switch language to ENG and try those too or just check them live on your script.

Comment: Would this not also select (123)456 or 23(456)78if that was present? I would not want that. Only 123 or 456

Comment: You are right, just put two spaces between numbers and %, ill edit in a sec

Comment: It won't find `123 this was a test` with the update, nor `testing 456`.

Comment: So now what i want is to find '123' but it can have any character which is non numeric beside it.
For example
,123, is fine
,123)
(123, is FINE
1234 is NOT FINE

Comment: yeah, it requires the digits to be surrounded with spaces, and `123 ` doesn't have space in front of it, while `456` doesn't have a space after it. Your previous example in table had those spaces, that's why i suggested it. I'll think of a way to rework it to work even if the space is just one sided.

Comment: Actually `'% 123 %'` means find a string of: 'space, 123, space'

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Just in case you missed this:

 
So now what i want is to find '123' but it can have any character which is non numeric beside it. For example ,123, is fine ,123) (123, is FINE 1234 is NOT FINE –

Comment: @Mahfuz So the question is answered or not? The accepting an answer is if the question is solved.

Comment: Its solved as in I can now find explicitly '123' and '456'. But i want to find these values with anything either side that is non numeric. So my question has been updated to query this too.

Comment: Added EDIT3 - as of now it should match your requirements perfectly. Chris85 had some great contribution on this.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a regex then use something that shouldn't be included on either side of the part that you DO want matched. Typically this would be a word boundary if you're looking for "whole words" in a string.

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

> [[:<:]], [[:>:]]
>
> These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and end of words, respectively. A word is a sequence of word characters that is not preceded by or followed by word characters. A word character is an alphanumeric character in the alnum class or an underscore (_).

So try something like this: (removing the dots will require that the 123/456 aren't in the middle somewhere)

```
Select * from TABLE where data REGEXP '[[:<:]](123|456)[[:>:]]';
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `LIKE` with wildcards?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `regexp` then use:

```
select * from TABLE where data REGEXP '(123).*(456)';
```

---

```
select '--- my name is 123 and my 456 is 789' REGEXP '(123).*(456)' ;
```

returns `1`

```
select '--- my name is 321 and my 654 is 987' REGEXP '(123).*(456)' ;
```

returns `0`

```
select '--- my name is 1234 and my 2 is 1' REGEXP '(123).*(456)' ;
```

returns `0`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ID from Table 
where patindex('%123%', Data) <> 0 
and patindex('%456%',Data) <> 0
```